# wp_list_categories in sidebar based on post_type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to get all categories given to posts in my custom post_type and show them as a list in the sidebar. How can i do that?

Also, based on the current category site that i am on i want not to use the default template category.php instead of that i want to use archive-myposttype.php to use my own layout based on the category.

All categories are default post categories, not custom taxonomies.

I have two custom_post_types (posttype1, posttype2) but with NO custom taxonomie, so it's dificult to filter and display only categories assigned to the custom post type posts.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you have to use raw sql:

```
<?php 
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT term_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships ON {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts on {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.object_id = {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID AND wp_3_posts.post_type ="custom_post" WHERE taxonomy = "category"';
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_col($query, 0);
$categories = get_terms(array("taxonomy" => "category", "object_ids" => $term_ids)); 
?>
```

Reference here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

For the second question, you can use the code above to find if this is the category you want to target and then inside category.php file load the custom template you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you said you want to display the categories as a list, I guess you don't want to add links to each categories listed. If it is so, then you can easily get categories for a post by using 'get_the_category()' function.

For your second question, I'm not sure whether you want custom template based on the category or post type, as a category can be present in both post types, so I can't see how you could achive this.

However, if you want to show custom template based on the category slug, you can easily create files and name them this way category-{category-slug}.php. so for category named 'photos' the filename will be 'category-photos.php'.